# PhP page get displayed online. But nothing displayed on localhost using view.php mod view and cid

Tags: php

I have develop php application with this url online that works fine and shows the internal page using `url view.php?mod=admin&view=doEditStudent&cId=10` as shown below:

[image]

But when i run it on localhost, the left menu is displayed but the internal page is not displayed. No change in the code.

Comment: Is ```cId``` a record from the database?

Comment: Does localhost have PHP installed? Are you executing the path correctly? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: I had a problem with <? } ?> short_open_tag. I traced the error using error reporting by using ini_set() in my config file. I set it the short_open_tag off from php.ini using short_open_tag=Off. Every thing worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are missing some data or files locally or you have some relative paths that are not the same on your local file system as on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with  short_open_tag. I traced the error using error reporting by using ini_set() in my config file. I set the short_open_tag off from php.ini using short_open_tag=Off. Every thing worked fine.